# Acess Point capability test

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I was carrying out a capability test for a wireless Access Point. As what I been told, the maximum throughput of the wireless AP is at about 500-600Mbps. Then I tried to injected 900Mbps to that AP and then observed that the AP would switch off and restarts. This behavior can be reproduced at everytime.

What I expected is the AP should have better traffic management to handle the traffic dynamically, rather than switching off instead.

Or could it be due to limitation of the chipset CPU of that Access Point? The CPU might not "smart" enough to handle the overload data.

Appreciate if anyone here can provide some insight on this case.

Many thanks!

Comment: Most APs state too much when it comes to throughput values. The only way to make sure is to practically test it or check an impartial review of the device (my model).

Comment: Actually I'm not concern about the throughput value. My thought is that the AP suppose not to switch off / restart when get bottom-neck. It should handle the large throughput dynamically, e.g. Negotiate the  allowed bandwidth with the device before start sending. Or something sort of Buffer management complementary technique.

Comment: In some cases, that's a firmware bug. If you don't have the latest one, try updating the firmware.